# React JS mapping an array inside a state array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components, mapping

So basically I have this issue. I'm relatively new to React JS. I've created a state and I've successfully mapped it except for one thing. Below is the state:

```
const [currProject, setCurrProject] = useState([{
            id: 4,
            title: "Title",
            desc: "Description",
            arr: ["these", "are", "array", "elements"]}]);
```

So then, like I said, I map this like so:

```
currProject.map(item =>(
     <div>
          <h1>{item.title}</h1>
          <p>{item.desc}</p>
          <div>
               <p>{item.arr}</p>
          </div>
     </div>
        ))
```

So basically where the p tag is, I want to put the elements in the array in the currProject state in separate p tags. So it would look something like this:

```
<p>these</p>
<p>are</p>
<p>array</p>
<p>elements</p>
```

But obviously I wouldn't want to hard code that. Because that array could have more or less elements in it. Basically what I'm asking is how do I map an array that's already inside a state array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map it just like you mapped the previous array.

```
    currProject.map((item, i) =>(
         <div key={i}>
              <h1>{item.title}</h1>
              <p>{item.desc}</p>
              <div>
                   {item.arr.map((item, i) => (
                    <p key={i}>{item}</p>
                   ))}
              </div>
         </div>
        ))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need use more `map` to render item.arr.

```
  {currProject.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
      <h1>{item.title}</h1>
      <p>{item.desc}</p>
      <div>
        {item.arr.map((item2, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{item2}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
```

**Note**: You need add a `key` in fist tag inside `map`